# Binding the visibility of app bar buttons to controls

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a very simple Windows Phone 8.1 app. This app has two screens, and for simplicity's sake and because I have some common functions, I've implemented both of these screens within `MainPage.xaml`. I want to bind the visibility of the AppBar buttons to these screens / panels. Here's what I tried

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" IsCompact="False" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ViewItemsPanel, Path=Visibility}" Label="Add" Click="AddButton_Click" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" IsCompact="False" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditItemPanel, Path=Visibility}" Label="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Save" IsCompact="False" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditItemPanel, Path=Visibility}" Label="Save" Click="SaveButton_Click" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - all three buttons are visible on both screens. I could create a dynamic property in code-behind for each of these but I thought there might be a nice elegant way to do something like this - is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppBar isn't in the same namespace as the page and so the bindings to the page's elements resolve. This is the case for any binding of the AppBar to the page.

You can set the AppBar's DataContext to the page in the page Loaded event and then bind to properties on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a grid panel to mimic the app bar, name the grid drop the app bar buttons in it and collapse or make visible as needed. Might not be the most elegant way to do it but it will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks Justin. slightly more elegant than my individual properties approach, if I cant find a pure xaml solution I may do that

Answer (score 0):

You can create several app bars in your code behind and set the ApplicationBar property of you page to the appbar you like to display.
I used this solution in a pivot view with 3 pages

```
var applicationBars = new List<Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar>();
private void MainPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (mainPivot.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: ApplicationBar = applicationBars[0]; break;
        case 1: ApplicationBar = applicationBars[1]; break;
        case 2: ApplicationBar = applicationBars[2]; break;
        ...
    }
}
```